# how to get authenticated user data

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a problem that I've been trying to solve for a long time. I have read courses about PHP sessions and I had proposals to use localstorage but to no avail

**The problem:**

Im working with angularJS and PHP backend, and I have 2 views, one 'login.html' and the other 'info.html', 2 controllers (one for the login function and the other for selecting the user's data) . I managed to do the authentication phase but for the second step I want that when the user authenticates, it will be redirected to other view (info.html) where all the information of this user will be displayed.
How can I store the data from login function and use it in the second controller

**login.php**

```
 <?php  
session_start();
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");  

 if(count($data) > 0)  

 { 

$Email=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->Email);
$password=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data->password);

$query = 'SELECT * FROM `client` WHERE (EmailClient = "'.$Email.'" AND   password= "'.$password.'")';

$q = mysqli_query($connect , $query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($q) > 0 )
  { 
       $_SESSION["logged_in"] = true; 
       $_SESSION["naam"] = $Email; 
       $result['email'] =$Email;
       $resultstring=json_encode($result);
       $resultstring=str_replace("null", '""', $resultstring);
       echo $resultstring;
       exit;

  } 
       $result['code'] = 603;
       $result['message'] ='The username or password are incorrect!';


$resultstring = json_encode($result);
$resultstring = str_replace("null",'""',$resultstring);
echo $resultstring;
exit;
}

?>
```

**loginCtrl**

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $location,$state,$http,$window){

    $scope.submit = function()
    {
        data = {
            'Email' : $scope.Email,
            'password' : $scope.password
    };

        $http.post('http://localhost/deb/login.php', data)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config,result)
        {
            console.log(data);
            $state.go('info');

             }
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config, result)
        {      
            console.log('error');   
        });
    }

});
```

**infoCtrl :**

```
app.controller('infoCtrl', function($scope, $http,$state,$filter){

    $scope.loadColis = function(){ 
              $http.get("http://localhost/deb/info.php")  
           .success(function(data){  
                $scope.names = data;  
           });
      }
```

**info.php**

```
...
$query = "SELECT * FROM client where ???" ;
....
```

I don't know how get user authenticated data, how can I do please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your Login controller use `$emit`

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, $location,$state,$http,$window){

    $scope.submit = function()
    {
        data = {
            'Email' : $scope.Email,
            'password' : $scope.password
    };

        $http.post('http://localhost/deb/login.php', data)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config,result)
        {
           //If the user is an authenticated user then make Api call to get authenticated user data using $http.get and pass the data to $emit

            $scope.$emit('authenticatedUserData', {data: data});                 
            $state.go('info');

             }
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config, result)
        {      
            console.log('error');   
        });
    }

});
```

And in your info Controller use `$on`

```
app.controller('infoCtrl', function($scope, $http,$state,$filter){
$scope.$on('authenticatedUserData', function (event, data) {
  // Logic goes here
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but how can I retreive authenticated user data in info controller and web service?